# Iterator stuck, causing infinite loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7, infinite-loop

In Python 2.7.3, I have created an automatic playing of a 2-player game in which each of 2 players, when it is their turn, from the following: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. If any of the 2 cards is a 6, the turn ends. Otherwise, the 2 values of the cards are added up, and 2 dice are rolled and their values are added up. The total number of points the player receives that turn is the sum of the two card values multiplied by the sum of the two die values. The first player to get to 300 points wins the game.

I want to be able to execute this "playing of the game" 100 times, displaying the results each time, and at the end of all games displaying the total number of times each player won. However, my `game` variable I am iterating over in my for loop is stuck at `1`, that is, the first game, causing an infinite loop.

Here is my code:

```
import random
playerone = 0
playertwo = 0
playeronewins = 0
playertwowins = 0
currentplayer = 1
scoreToWin = 300
games = 100
for game in range(1,games+1):
    while playerone < scoreToWin and playertwo < scoreToWin:
        cardone = random.randint(2,6)
        cardtwo = random.randint(2,6)
        if cardone != 6 and cardtwo != 6:
            cardtotal = cardone + cardtwo
            dieone = random.randint(1,6)
            dietwo = random.randint(1,6)
            dietotal = dieone + dietwo
            points = cardtotal * dietotal
            if currentplayer == 1:
                playerone += points
            else:
                playertwo += points
            if playerone >= scoreToWin:
                print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 1 wins with ' + str(playerone) + ' points. Player 2 loses with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points.'
                playeronewins += 1
                if game != games:
                    playerone = 0
                    playertwo = 0
            if playertwo >= scoreToWin:
                print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 2 wins with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points. Player 1 loses with ' + str(playerone) + ' points.'
                playertwowins += 1
                if game != games:
                    playerone = 0
                    playertwo = 0
        currentplayer = 2 if currentplayer == 1 else 1
print 'Player 1 won ' + str(playeronewins) + ' times.'
print 'Player 2 won ' + str(playertwowins) + ' times.'
```

What is causing this problem, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Your diagnosis of the problem is incorrect - the `for` loop is guaranteed to terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the player scores to 0 *inside the while loop*, so it continues forever.

De-dent the score tests:

```
while playerone < scoreToWin and playertwo < scoreToWin:
    # card game loop
    # this line still belongs in the loop:
    currentplayer = 2 if currentplayer == 1 else 1

# *Now* test for the scores, *outside* the while loop
if playerone >= scoreToWin:
    print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 1 wins with ' + str(playerone) + ' points. Player 2 loses with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points.'
    playeronewins += 1
if playertwo >= scoreToWin:
    print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 2 wins with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points. Player 1 loses with ' + str(playerone) + ' points.'
    playertwowins += 1
playerone = 0
playertwo = 0
```

No need to test for `game != games` in there either.

With these changes a test run produces:

```
Game 1: Player 2 wins with 330 points. Player 1 loses with 214 points.
Game 2: Player 2 wins with 301 points. Player 1 loses with 261 points.
Game 3: Player 1 wins with 348 points. Player 2 loses with 207 points.
# .. ~ ..
Game 98: Player 2 wins with 344 points. Player 1 loses with 248 points.
Game 99: Player 1 wins with 323 points. Player 2 loses with 173 points.
Game 100: Player 2 wins with 354 points. Player 1 loses with 105 points.
Player 1 won 45 times.
Player 2 won 55 times.
```

Comment: @videoeditor5000: Anything else wrong I can assist with? I tested the code with these changes, and things work.

Comment: @videoeditor5000: You should consider accepting this answer if it helped you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the wonderfully quick reply. This was my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow, so I was delighted to see such a quick, helpful and detailed response time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop never terminates, so you never get out of game 1. The best solution is to refactor your code so it's easier to understand and reason about. (Hint: Use some functions.) However, as a quick-hack fix to the original code, simply add the following `break` statements:

```
        if playerone >= scoreToWin:
            print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 1 wins with ' + str(playerone) + ' points. Player 2 loses with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points.'
            playeronewins += 1
            if game != games:
                playerone = 0
                playertwo = 0
   >>>>     break
        if playertwo >= scoreToWin:
            print 'Game ' + str(game) + ': Player 2 wins with ' + str(playertwo) + ' points. Player 1 loses with ' + str(playerone) + ' points.'
            playertwowins += 1
            if game != games:
                playerone = 0
                playertwo = 0
   >>>>     break
```